# Filtering out lead conversions from process builder

Tags: process-builder

Is there any way to identify when lead conversion has triggered a process builder workflow and prevent it from doing so?

For example, if I have a PBR functioning when a task is created, I *don't* want it to run if that task is created during lead conversion.

**EDIT:**

More context on what's happening... I have a PBR that logs the last activity date on either the lead or contact record. However, I get the following error when the activity is trying to be created during the lead conversion process:

> Error Occurred: The flow tried to update these records:
>   0031N00001M6aLwQAJ. This error occurred:
>   ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK: . For details, see API
>   Exceptions.---The flow tried to update these records:
>   0031N00001M6aLwQAJ. This error occurred:
>   ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK: . For details, see API
>   Exceptions.---The flow tried to update these records:
>   0031N00001M6aLwQAJ. This error occurred:
>   ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK: . For details, see API
>   Exceptions.---The flow tried to update these records:
>   0031N00001M6aLwQAJ. This error occurred:
>   ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK: . For details, see API
>   Exceptions.---The flow tried to update these records:
>   0031N00001M6aLwQAJ. This error occurred:
>   ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK: . For details, see API
>   Exceptions.---The flow tried to update these records:
>   0031N00001M6aLwQAJ. This error occurred:
>   ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK: . For details, see API
>   Exceptions.---The flow tried to update these records:
>   0031N00001M6aLwQAJ. This error occurred:
>   ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK: . For details, see API
>   Exceptions.---The flow tried to update these records:
>   0031N00001M6aLwQAJ. This error occurred:
>   ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK: . For details, see API
>   Exceptions.---The flow tried to update these records:
>   0031N00001M6aLwQAJ. This error occurred:
>   ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK: . For details, see API
>   Exceptions.---The flow tried to update these records:
>   0031N00001M6aLwQAJ. This error occurred:
>   ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK: . For details, see API
>   Exceptions.---The flow tried to update these records:
>   0031N00001M6aLwQAJ. This error occurred:
>   ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK: . For details, see API
>   Exceptions.---The flow tried to update these records:
>   0031N00001M6aLwQAJ. This error occurred:
>   ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK: . For details, see API
>   Exceptions.---The flow tried to update these records: null. This error
>   occurred: DUPLICATE_VALUE: Maximum number of duplicate updates in one
>   batch (12 allowed). Attempt to update Id more than once in this Api
>   call: 0031N00001M6aLw. For details, see API Exceptions.---The flow
>   tried to update these records: null. This error occurred:
>   DUPLICATE_VALUE: Maximum number of duplicate updates in one batch (12
>   allowed). Attempt to update Id more than once in this Api call:
>   0031N00001M6aLw. For details, see API Exceptions.

Here's the relevant parts of the PBR:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Need more info here... what causes a task to be created during Lead conversion?

Comment: @CharlesT added more info to the post

Comment: Thanks. Why is an activity being generated *during* lead conversion though? That part I don't get.

Comment: On the lead conversion page it  includes a section on task information by default. Even if you don't input anything, it still triggers the PBR and fails for some reason

Comment: Oh I see, so it's moving Tasks from the Leads to the newly created records. Maybe you could check (via 3 character prefix of the ID) if the `WhoId` of the Task is changing from a Lead to no longer a Lead?

Comment: How would you be able to tell that it's undergoing the change from Lead to Contact? I'm basically identifying it as a Contact by saying it has an AccountId, but I don't know if there's some way to see that it's in the middle of the conversion process?

Comment: I figure if LEFT(PRIORVALUE([Task].WhoId)) = "00Q" and LEFT([Task].WhoId) = '003', then it suggests this Task is being moved from Lead to Contact.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to know a Task is coming from a lead conversion unless your conversion process sets a field value in the task record to flag it as such.

With Contact and Opp, you can see if they originated from a lead conversion by looking at the ConvertedContactId and ConvertedOpportunityId the Lead object, but you would need a visual flow or Apex trigger to do this query.

Answer (score -1):

There is one workaround i have found out. The error occurs because there are too many tasks. All of the task are trying to update the object. If you convert the lead, all tasks are updated because of the AccountId Field. Is the Task related to a lead it is null.

So you have add the follwing criteria:

"accountid ischanged is false"

So the workflow is not fired when you convert the lead.

Comment: Hi joe, welcome! This has been flagged as low quality, can you expand on it a little?

Comment: Hi Matt, i have tried to make my post more clear